# Linking to an external URL in Javadoc?

Tags: java, url, javadoc, hyperlink

Something like:

```
/**
 * See {@linktourl http://google.com}
 */
```

Answer (score 1425, accepted):

This creates a "See Also" heading containing the link, i.e.:

```
/**
 * @see <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
 */
```

will render as:

> **See Also:**
>              http://google.com

whereas this:

```
/**
 * See <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
 */
```

will create an in-line link:

> See http://google.com

Comment: If anyone is interested, since I just had to look it up: According to the [Javadoc spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#orderoftags) the `@see` tag comes *after* the `@param`/`@return` tags and *before* the `@since`/`@serial`/`@deprecated` tags.

Comment: Just in case, Intellij 13 does not seem to support this tag. It does support in-line links. Is the tag somehow deprecated?

Comment: When I use this with Maven, it warns about a missing final greater than symbol - anyone know why?

Comment: I recommend `<a href="http://google.com" target="_top">http://google.com</a>.`  The reason for adding target="_top" is because some of the generated javadoc html files make use of frames, and you probably want the navigation to affect the whole page rather than just the current frame.

Comment: If you get a warning like "warning - Tag \@see: missing final '>':", make sure you don't have two hyperlinks in the same \@see directive. Instead, use one link per \@see.

Comment: why is it so complicated to add a URL link to a javadoc ? who thought that HTML was a good idea... /facepalm

Comment: If someone else is as lame as me and searching for the difference between the in-line version and the other for hours: Mind the '@' before 'See' ;)

Comment: As a follow up to @Timo s remark: Intelij 2019.1 now does properly display a "see also" entry

Comment: This is soooo.. 1997!

Answer (score 203):

Taken from the [javadoc spec](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#@see)

`@see <a href="URL#value">label</a>` :
Adds a link as defined by `URL#value`. The `URL#value` is a relative or absolute URL. The Javadoc tool distinguishes this from other cases by looking for a less-than symbol (`<`) as the first character.

For example : `@see <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`

Comment: Weird; I swear I only added in the backticks; I don't know where the example went to...

Comment: I think we had some kind of concurrent edit problem.  I was putting them in also.

Comment: Fair enough. You're missing the backticks in the first line of your blockquote, though....

Comment: @see is not needed. The javadocs can be formatted with html tags, so it's only necessary the "a" tag.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas True, but the original question implies this is how it's being used. It's useful to know that it specifically _does_ work in a see-also field, which is where a lot of people will want it.

Answer (score 47):

Javadocs don't offer any special tools for external links, so you should just use standard html:

```
See <a href="http://groversmill.com/">Grover's Mill</a> for a history of the
Martian invasion.
```

or

```
@see <a href="http://groversmill.com/">Grover's Mill</a> for a history of 
the Martian invasion.
```

Don't use `{@link ...}` or `{@linkplain ...}` because these are for links to the javadocs of other classes and methods.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to find a clear answer from the Oracle site. The following is from `javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.java`:

```
/**
 * See {@link <a href="http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1">HTTP/1.1 documentation</a>}.
 */
public static final String ACCEPT = "Accept";

/**
 * See {@link <a href="http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.2">HTTP/1.1 documentation</a>}.
 */
public static final String ACCEPT_CHARSET = "Accept-Charset";
```

Comment: What is the significance of wrapping the `<a>` html tag with the `{@link ...}`?

Comment: This is probably a mistake because [the javadoc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#@link) does not mention this form, in it does not make a difference from a raw `<a>`.

Comment: The {@link xxx} here isn't right. {@link xxx} is for linking to other classes and methods in your source code. It's unnecessary here. The rest of it is fine.

Comment: This construct is not allowed by Java 8 standards (doclint on).

Comment: This is plain wrong. The correct usage as per [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link) and [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#{@link}) is `{@link package.class#member label}`

Comment: Tip: hey you could earn the `Disciplined` badge by deleting this post (which seems to have been voted as less helpful than the others)

Comment: @LukeUsherwood The problem is that SO scoring algorithm gives you more positive points for an upvote than negative points for a downvote. Thus if you have 10 upvotes and 10 downvotes, and you are missing the self-discipline, you are not motivated to delete your (apparently wrong) answer :( I tried several times to flag such questions but in vain, the moderators answered me that they do not delete answers on the basis the they (= the answers) are incorrect.