# How to add a hyperlink in a comment in eclipse javadocs

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, comments

I would like Eclipse to resolve e.g. this hyperlink in a javadoc:

```
/*
 * for reference, look here: http://www.google.com
 */
```

The goal would be that the hyperlink is just "clickable" as any normal hyperlink (e.g. as in pdf or doc files).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking to an external URL in Javadoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082050/linking-to-an-external-url-in-javadoc)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is only possible in a JavaDoc comment!

Example:

```
/**
 * for reference, look here: <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
 */
```

After generating the Javadoc, you have a normal hyperlink. An other way is to watch in the JavaDoc view of Eclipse!

**EDIT:**
Another way in a normal comment is to press the CTRL and click with the left mouse botton on the link!

Comment: The "Ctrl-Thing" works in many places. Search for "hyperlinking" in the preferences....