# Use URL in Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

Example:

```
/**
     * @see <a
     * href="http://localhost:8080/MyApp/App/v1/thing/?param1=24421">URL
     * example thing</a>
     *
     * @param param1 myparam
     * @param request extends the ServletRequest interface to provide request
     * information for HTTP servlets.
     * @return param1
     */
    @GET
    @Path("thing")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String thing(@QueryParam("param1") String param1, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        return param1;

    }
```

When i generate Javadoc, I´m receiving this error from netbeans: error: invalid url.

How should I put in URL instead?

Comment: Check [Linking to an external URL in Javadoc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082050/linking-to-an-external-url-in-javadoc)

Comment: Note that you're linking to `localhost` which won't be accessible from other users.